# CellTable with custom Header containing SearchBox and ListBox

Tags: gwt

How to create event on safe html. As  I want to do filtering for column in celltable.
So I added search box at header in table. I want to access textbox and do some event on textbox.

[image]

Code:

```
   final MultiSelectionModel<MasterTable> selectionModel=new MultiSelectionModel<MasterTable>();
        CellTable<MasterTable> cell=new CellTable<MasterTable>();
        cell.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<MasterTable> createCheckboxManager());

        Column<MasterTable, Boolean> checkColumn = new Column<MasterTable, Boolean>(new CheckboxCell(true, false)) {
            @Override
            public Boolean getValue(MasterTable object) {
                return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
            }
        };
        cell.addColumn(checkColumn);
        cell.setColumnWidth(checkColumn, 20, Unit.PX);
        personCollection.getList().add(new MasterTable("Art", "Shake", 21));
        personCollection.getList().add(new MasterTable("Joe", "Black", 47));
        personCollection.getList().add(new MasterTable("Sam", "PArish", 97));

        TextColumn<MasterTable> namecolumn = new TextColumn<MasterTable>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(MasterTable s) {
                return s.getName();
            }
        };



        TextColumn<MasterTable> lastNameColumn = new TextColumn<MasterTable>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(MasterTable s) {
                return s.getLastName();
            }
        };
        TextColumn<MasterTable> ageColumn = new TextColumn<MasterTable>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(MasterTable s) {
                return Integer.toString(s.getAge());
            }
        };

//        cell.addColumn(namecolumn,"Name");
        SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        builder.appendHtmlConstant("<input type=\"text\" id=\"nameInput\" /><br/><br/><select><option>one</option></select><br/><center><b>Name</b></center>");
        cell.addColumn(namecolumn,builder.toSafeHtml());
        SafeHtmlBuilder builder1 = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        builder1.appendHtmlConstant("<input type=\"text\"/><br/><br/><select><option>one</option></select><br/><center><b>Last name</b></center>");
        cell.addColumn(lastNameColumn,builder1.toSafeHtml());
        SafeHtmlBuilder builder2 = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        builder2.appendHtmlConstant("<input type=\"text\"/><br/><br/><select><option>one</option></select><br/><center><b>Age</b></center>");
        cell.addColumn(ageColumn,builder2.toSafeHtml());
        personCollection.addDataDisplay(cell);
        verticalPanel.add(searchpanel);
        verticalPanel.add(cell);
        RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(verticalPanel);
        final Element nameInput = DOM.getElementById("nameInput");

        if(nameInput!=null)
        {
            Event.sinkEvents(nameInput, Event.ONCHANGE);
            Event.setEventListener(nameInput, new EventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
                    personCollection.setFilter(nameInput.getInnerText());
                    personCollection.refresh();
                }
            });
        }
```

First problem I am getting *nameInput* is **null**. why?

This is just sample. I want to create this column dynamically.
so is it possible to add DOM event dynamically for run time generated DOM element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it is to use a `Cell` for your header, such as a `TextInputCell`, with a `ValueUpdater` to handle the change.

Comment: Thanks, But I want to have two feature like input, select so I have to implement *TextInputCell* and *SelectionCell* on header. right? how can I achieve both? I could not found any way that's why I am looking for `Dom` element.

Comment: `CompositeCell` with `FieldUpdater`? (never tried it in a header though) Or a custom cell if you're OK going low-level (SafeHtml + onBrowserEvent; you might want to use UiRenderer for a slightly higher-level view)

Comment: Thank you so much :) I have tried with all approach as 1) In `SafeHtml + onBrowserEvent`, I am facing focus event issue so it almost done but not completed.  2) With `CompositeCell with FieldUpdater`. It's done. In that layout issue as you know it shows element in horizontal order. how can I align cell in `vertically`?

Comment: Vertically done as apply style *<div style='display:block;'>* to cell on `render`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code-snippet does not show where you add the verticalpanel to the page, if that happens after searching the dom-tree it obviously does not work.

If `SafeHtml` containing the input is appended to page before searching it from DOM tree the element is found and one can listen events from it. Snippet bellow works for me (you need container with id container on page where get-app is loaded).

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
    builder.appendHtmlConstant("<input type=\"text\" id=\"nameInput\" /><br/><br/><select><option>one</option></select><br/><center><b>Name</b></center>");

    RootPanel.get("container").add(new HTML(builder.toSafeHtml()));

    final Element nameInput = DOM.getElementById("nameInput");
    if (nameInput != null) {
        Event.sinkEvents(nameInput, Event.ONCHANGE);
        Event.setEventListener(nameInput, new EventListener() {
            public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
                Window.alert(nameInput.getInnerHTML());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See updated question. This things I already know. Thanks. As I created same sample earlier that is worked perfect. but with *CellTable*, it is not working. I don't understand. why?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand what's going on is to study the code of [Custom Data Grid](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid)

In particular you need to see the code of `CustomHeaderBuilder`

I think it's unfortunate that the [Showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html) does not include an example of header search boxes, and everyone has to do this from scratch.